# How to get the id attribute of a row when one if its child elements is clicked?

Tags: jquery, row

How do I return the id attribute of the row in which a link resides?  I've tried different variations, but the best I've been able to get is "undefined"...

The html looks like this:

```
<tr id="30">
  <td>Parker</td>
  <td><a href="#" id="id783900" class="section-id">Select</a></td>
</tr>
```

One of the things I tried is this:

```
$("a.section-id").click(function() {
  var parenttr = $(this).parent().parent().attr("id");
  alert(parenttr);
});
```

I also tried this:

```
$("a.section-id").click(function() {
  var parenttr = $(this).parent('tr').attr("id");
  alert(parenttr);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
$(this).closest('tr').attr('id');
```

Comment: +1 nice method.  I've been using `.parents('whatever:first')` forever, and now I see this!

Answer (score 0):

parent() only checks the immediate parent. To traverse up the tree, use parents().

```
var parenttr = $(this).parents('tr').attr("id");
```

EDIT:

treeface is correct. Use closest() for this use case. parents() does extra work that you don't need for this problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a.section-id').click(function(e) {
    var parent_id = $(this).parents('tr:first').attr('id');
    alert(parent_id);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```